# Alinhar listas de tamanhos diferentes na div em Bootstrap

Tags: php, html, html5, twitter-bootstrap, css

Tenho algumas listas que são alimentados através de uma consulta ao banco de dados, ou seja, a quantidade que irá mostrar é incerta, porém eu limito mostrar até 5 registros por categoria.

Como está:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uma lista está ocupando o "espaço" da outra e entao quero quebrar em "rows", basicamente assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código:

```
<div class="col-md-12 main-content">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="box">
            <h3 class="box-title">Categoria</h3>
            <ul class="box-list">
                <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a class="read-more" href="#">Ver Todos <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="box">
            <h3 class="box-title">Categoria</h3>
            <ul class="box-list">
                <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a class="read-more" href="#">Ver Todos <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="box">
            <h3 class="box-title">Categoria</h3>
            <ul class="box-list">
                <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a class="read-more" href="#">Ver Todos <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="box">
            <h3 class="box-title">Categoria</h3>
            <ul class="box-list">
                <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a class="read-more" href="http://192.168.31.50/faq/view/teste-de-envio-para-web">Ver Todos <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="box">
            <h3 class="box-title">Categoria</h3>
            <ul class="box-list">
                <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a class="read-more" href="#">Ver Todos <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vc pode tratar o .row que as listas estão dentro com `display:flex` e `flex-wrap` assim vc evita que as listas fiquem "encavaladas" e joga o conteúdo que não couber para a "linha" de baixo

Para entender melhor como fica veja o snippet abaixo *(exiba também em "Página toda" para ver o resultado)*

```css
.listas {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    
        <div class="col-md-12 main-content">
                <div class="row listas">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="box">
                            <h3 class="box-title">Categoria</h3>
                            <ul class="box-list">
                                <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <a class="read-more" href="#">Ver Todos <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="box">
                            <h3 class="box-title">Categoria</h3>
                            <ul class="box-list">
                                <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <a class="read-more" href="#">Ver Todos <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="box">
                            <h3 class="box-title">Categoria</h3>
                            <ul class="box-list">
                                <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <a class="read-more" href="#">Ver Todos <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="box">
                            <h3 class="box-title">Categoria</h3>
                            <ul class="box-list">
                                <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <a class="read-more" href="http://192.168.31.50/faq/view/teste-de-envio-para-web">Ver Todos <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="box">
                            <h3 class="box-title">Categoria</h3>
                            <ul class="box-list">
                                <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <a class="read-more" href="#">Ver Todos <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Funcionou, acabei esquecendo dessa possibilidade, obrigado!

Comment: @Piupz Tranquilo jovem estamos aqui pra isso! E se quiser as 5 listas na mesma fileira basta tirar o flex-wrap: wrap

Comment: Obrigado! Otima solução. Pode ser configurado também diretamente na classe row no arquivo de estilização onde foi implementada.

Comment: @LucasCoelho valeu jovem! Pode fazer dessa maneira sim, mas ai TODAS as .row vão ficar como essa classe, e pode atrapalhar o seu grid em outro lugar, pois isso preferi criar uma classe só com essas propriedades, ai vc pode usar apenas na .row que quiser! Lembrando que aqui o Boostrap é v3 não tem as classes de flexbox da v4